# ModRewrite with HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, canonical-link

I'm using the following mod rewrites to ensure not only canonical URLs, but also that the site is displayed using HTTPS:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
// It think the problem must be here --^

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rto12\.ca$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.rto12.ca/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php?
RewriteRule ^index\.php?$ https://www.rto12.ca/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html?
RewriteRule ^index\.html?$ https://www.rto12.ca/ [R=301,L]
```

My problem comes when you try to go here: `rto12.ca`... The browser takes you here: `https://www.rto12.ca/https://rto12.ca/'

It's the first condition/rule that's causing this.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you using to force the HTTPS? I don't see a rule that checks for that here.

Comment: Oh good point Tim, and probably where my issue lies:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This rule:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

...will just rewrite the request to `https://rto12.ca/REQUEST_URI`, and then pass it off to the next rule (the input to the next rule, which you append to the end of the request, will be `https://rto12.ca/REQUEST_URI`). However, for it to work properly, you need it to redirect immediately:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It's likely possible to combine all of your rules into at most a single redirect, so let me play around with it a bit and I'll see what I can come up with, then I'll update the answer. Adding the flags should fix your problem either way, though.

**Edit**: I think this should take everything in one go:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}        =off   [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.(html|php)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(index\.(html|php))|(.*)$ https://www.%2/$3 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This definitely did it Tim, thanks!  If you come up with a single redirect to do what I'm doing here I'd love to see it.  Thanks again.

Comment: @jeerose - Cool, glad it's working. I've updated the answer with a combined redirect block, see if that takes care of everything you wanted.

Comment: It does indeed.  Thank-you so much for your time, Tim.